# How to write to the cloud quickly?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I am wondering how to most quickly log data during cloud execution. I do not need anything fancy: all I want to do is persist certain information for later analysis, with minimal blocking for the end user. A solution that involves dumping data and then periodically cleaning it up with a `ScheduledTask` would be acceptable. All of the code will run in the cloud. The `Permissions` need to be private.

For example, say I want to track which users call certain functions I have deployed.

`CloudSymbol` is faster in the cloud than in Mathematica, but it is still slow.

```
CloudSymbol@"list1" = {};
AppendTo[CloudSymbol@"list1", $RequesterWolframUUID] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.070239, $RequesterWolframUUID}

Before we compare timings, briefly note this behavior:

```
CloudSymbol@"list1"
```

> {$RequesterWolframUUID}

```
CloudEvaluate[CloudSymbol@"list1"]
```

> {"0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446"}

```
CloudSymbol@"list1"
```

> {$RequesterWolframUUID}

Returning to timings,

```
CloudEvaluate[AppendTo[CloudSymbol@"list1",$RequesterWolframUUID]//AbsoluteTiming]
  //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.866184, {1.723062, {0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446,0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446}}}

It is worth pointing out that the assignment in the cloud caused `$RequesterWolframUUID` to be resolved at that time. Compare this result to the behavior above.

```
CloudSymbol@"list1"
```

> {0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446,0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446}

`URLFetch` is marginally faster than `CloudEvaluate`.

```
logUser=CloudDeploy@APIFunction[{},AppendTo[CloudSymbol@"list1",$RequesterWolframUUID]&];
URLFetch@logUser // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.500356,{"0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446", "0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446", "0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446"}

However, this doesn't work when running in the cloud.

```
CloudEvaluate[URLFetch@logUser // AbsoluteTiming] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> (* errors, because the page was a login prompt *)

I tried `CloudEvaluate`-ing `CloudConnect` first, with no luck.

Also, `URLFetch` and `URLFetchAsynchronous` are inconsistent.

```
URLFetchAsynchronous[logUser,#&]
```

> URLFetchAsynchronous[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b2305e35-a643-4a52-a94d-575e0019b0d2"],#1&]

```
URLFetchAsynchronous[URLBuild@logUser,#&]
```

> AsynchronousTaskObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b2305e35-a643-4a52-a94d-575e0019b0d2", 5, 15817848933037716543]

But even putting the syntax aside, handling the `"data"` event revealed that `URLFetchAsynchronous` is getting the login prompt, as in the cloud, so the function was not evaluated.

Lastly, the documentation says `PutAppend` has been updated to work with cloud objects, but I don't know how to use it.

```
list2 = CloudPut[$RequesterWolframUUID, "list2"];
$RequesterWolframUUID >>> list2 (* fast, no errors *)
CloudGet@"list2"
```

> $RequesterWolframUUID

```
PutAppend[$RequesterWolframUUID, URLBuild@list2]
```

> OpenAppend::noopen: Cannot open https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446/list2.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File operations do exactly what I need. Read/write are plenty fast.

Writes:

```
f := CloudEvaluate[(
  o = OpenAppend["user-call-log"];
  Write[o, $RequesterWolframUUID];
  Close[o]) // AbsoluteTiming];

f & /@ Range@5
```

> {{0.006766, "user-call-log"}, {0.006421, "user-call-log"}, {0.006456, "user-call-log"}, {0.006865, "user-call-log"}, {0.006581, "user-call-log"}}

Reads:

```
CloudEvaluate[(
  i = OpenRead["user-call-log"];
  ReadList[i]) // AbsoluteTiming]
```

> {0.004605, {"0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446","0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446","0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446","0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446","0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446"}}

I hope this is helpful to others.